# Sending data between threads using pipes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

I have 3 threads - I have to read something in the first one, count characters in the second, and make an output in the third. So I'm using two pipes here; for the 1st - 2nd threads, and 2nd - 3rd.

However, it doesn't work at all. I mean, I can type the string in the console, but then nothing happenes, there's no output.

What's wrong here?

Also, is this possible to add something like "Type string here: " in the first thread somewhere? Adding it in the while loop seems to produce strange results - it displays randomly after running the program :P

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

int first[2];
int second[2];

void *input(void *ptr)
{
   while(1)
   {
      char str[100];
      int result;

      result = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, sizeof(str));
      if(result <= 0)
      {
         if(result == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[1]);
         exit(2);
      }
      if(write(first[1], str, result) != result)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }
   }
}

void *countChars(void *ptr)
{
   int result, result2, count = 0;
   char str[100];

   while(1)
   {
      result = read(first[0], str, sizeof(str));
      if(result <= 0)
      {
         if(result == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[0]);
         close(second[1]);
         exit(2);
      }
      if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, result) != result)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }

      while(str[count] != '\0') count++;

      write(second[1], &count, sizeof(count));
   }
}

void *output(void *ptr)
{
   int result2, count = 0;
   char str[100];

   while(1)
   {
      result2 = read(second[0], str, sizeof(str));
      if(result2 <= 0)
      {
         if(result2 == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(second[0]);
         exit(2);
      }
      if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, result2) != result2)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }

      while(str[count] != '\0') count++;

      printf("Writer: %d\n", count - 1);
   }
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t t1, t2, t3;

   if(pipe(first) == -1)
   {
      printf("First pipe error");
      exit(1);
   }

   if(pipe(second) == -1)
   {
      printf("Second pipe error");
      exit(1);
   }

   pthread_create(&t1, NULL, input, NULL);
   pthread_create(&t2, NULL, countChars, NULL);
   pthread_create(&t3, NULL, output, NULL);

   pthread_join(t1, NULL);
   pthread_join(t2, NULL);
   pthread_join(t3, NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using threads to do this?

Comment: Ok, well, let's say I read exactly 100 characters...it still doesn't work, the output is 0.

Comment: You don't need to read 100 chars.  Alk is uncharacteristic mistaken.  You will read whatever is there to be read even if it is less than 100.

Comment: It looks like you are trying in thread 2 to write an integer `write(second[1], &count, sizeof(count));` to the pipe and then read it as a string `result2 = read(second[0], str, sizeof(str));`in the 3rd thread.  Then you base the output of thread 3 on `while(str[count] != '\0') count++;` and the first byte of the int could well be zero.  So you always output 0.

Comment: So what's the proper output in the 3rd thread? Result2 always holds 4, no idea why, and str seems to be empty.

Comment: It holds 4 because that is the size of the int that you are reading.

Comment: exit() will terminate the process, if I'm not mistaken. You should use pthread_exit() instead, or just return from the function. Then, you are somehow assuming that the strings are NUL-terminated (in which case you could use strlen()) but that's nowhere guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `countChars` function to count until a newline and write the int "count"

```
void *countChars(void *ptr)
{
   int result, result2, count = 0;
   char str[100];

   while(1)
   {
      result = read(first[0], str, sizeof(str));
      if(result <= 0)
      {
         if(result == -1)
            perror("read");
         close(first[0]);
         close(second[1]);
         exit(2);
      }

      if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, result) != result)
      {
         perror("write");
         exit(2);
      }

      //while(str[count] != '\0') count++;
      while(str[count] != '\n') count++;

      write(second[1], &count, sizeof(count));

      count = 0;
   }
}
```

And the `output` function to read the sizeof an int into an int variable.

```
void *output(void *ptr)
{
   int result2, count = 0;
   //char str[100];

   while(1)
   {
      //result2 = read(second[0], str, sizeof(str));
      result2 = read(second[0], &count, sizeof(count));
      if(result2 < sizeof(count))
      {
         close(second[0]);
         exit(2);
      }

      printf("Writer: %d\n", count);
   }
}
```

This works ok because only countChars is writing to the 2nd pipe.  A pipe write/read is atomic up to PIPE_BUF chars and an int is way less than that so the reads are predictable.